# How to configure Kendo Dropdownlist to work with Grid popup editor template

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've been struggling with the Kendo dropdownlist for 2 days now and just can't seem to get it configured correctly.

How do I get the Kendo Dropdownlist to show the current item of the @Model?  This is my code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ShortDescription, new { @class="wide200;" })

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("importance")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 250px" })
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .DataValueField("ID")
        .DataSource(source => {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("GetImportanceList", "Home");
            })
            .ServerFiltering(true);
        })
        .SelectedIndex(0)
)
```

And in my controller:

```
public ActionResult GetImportanceList()
    {
        GenericRepository<Importance> _repository = new GenericRepository<Importance>(_context);
        IEnumerable<ImportanceViewModel> list = _repository.Get().ConvertToViewModelList();
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Problem is with SelectedIndex(0) which is set to the first item.  How can I set it to whatever is in the model?  It's very simple to do for the textbox (first line in the code): model => model.ShortDescription.  But how does this work for the dropdownlist?

I don't just want to set it upon the showing of the editor, but also want the grid to know what the new selection is after I click the Update button.

Note that this is in a custom template for the grid popup editor.

Comment: Put Model and its properties here to solve. I had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

You have to pass DropDownListId in model and ListItems.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m=>m.DropDownListId)
        .Name("importance")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 250px" })
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .DataValueField("ID")
        .DataSource(source => {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("GetImportanceList", "Home");
            })
            .ServerFiltering(true);
        })
        .SelectedIndex(0)
)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeet.  I noticed that you are using DropDownListFor in stead of the DropDownList.  You also passed the ID of, I suppose, the ID of the property of the ViewModel (TaskViewModel in my case) that I want to change, thus ImportanceID.  It is still showing the first item in the list, not the currently selected Importance.  I also removed the .SelectedIndex(0), but no difference.  Changing and saving the importance doesn't work either.  Seems like it's completely ignoring the model.  Any ideas?

Comment: I asked this question to Telerik.  Apparently the Name mustn't be assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question to Telerik. Apparently the Name mustn't be assigned.